# System Log Event Viewer will not display

Tags: windows-vista, data-recovery, event-viewer

Am trying to view the System Event Log on someones laptop that is misbehaving.  botted in safe mode, load event viewer and click on system and it tells me "Data is invalid (13)".  Tried clearing the log and saving to disk but I get a message telling me that a parameter is incorrect!

Think there may be some useful info in it so am trying to salvage it to work out why this laptop occasionally doesn't boot.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Could the event viewer be reconstructed in a Linux livecd?

Comment: Did you check services (Control Panel->Admin Tools->Services) to make sure the Windows Event Log is started?  The start-up type should be automatic.

Comment: I can access the application log fine when in safe mode so the event log service must be started.  It is just the system log that is playing up.